# Deploying Mean Stack Application on Heroku Issue

Tags: node.js, angular, express, heroku, mean

This is my first time building a MEAN stack application and I built it locally. Now I am trying to host it on heroku and I think I messed it up. I went through different questions here and most of them said both angular and express needs to be in one single app. I din't know that, So here's my current folder structure.

```
Project Root Folder
|
| 
|------ Frontend (Angular App)
|
|
|------- Backend (Express App)
```

I tried searching everywhere but couldn't figure out what changes I need to make to my current project structure. Any tips or help or even a link to a guide would be much appreciated.

Comment: whats your error logs in heroku?

Comment: If you want to serve from a single dyno, the Express app will have to serve the build output from the Angular app as static content, alongside serving the APIs the client consumes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thats what I want to do. Can you point me to a tutorial if possible? I would really appreciate it

Comment: Backend and frontend are two seprate things you can host it at different different url althought you can build your SPA frontend and put the content inside express static folder and can use it in that way? other wise host it seprately and connect it using api url :)

Answer (score 0):

For hosting as a single app

1. first build the angular app
2. host the build folder of front end in the backend express app as

`app.use('*', express.static('Frontend/build/'))`

3. in start script of backend build the angular app and start the server file(`index.js`)
4. inside the server file use port from the environment variables, heroku will automatically assign you with an port which will be pointed to the dynamos url

you acn also follow this [article](https://medium.com/@BaaniLeen/deploying-mean-stack-app-to-heroku-tips-and-tricks-5bd43a967f8c)